# AppleScript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, finder

What is the equivalent below code in Javascript?
Is this apple script convertable to java script?

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set position of Finder window 1 to {607, 276}
    close Finder window 1
end tell
```

Thanks.

Comment: This might do what you want: http://jstalk.org/

Comment: I want to run this code by JavascriptCore framework. Is it possible? I am Windows programmer and beginner in Mac.

Comment: check out JSTalk, as linked above by @inkedmn – it’s built on top of JavascriptCore. Just out of interest: why do you want to use JavaScript for this?

Comment: Because Javascript is public and popular and I am familiar with it. 
Can I do Scripting InDesign CS4, CS5, ... with js talk?
How I can reference Application Object? and can I use it in carbon apps?
Tnx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the release of OS X Yosemite, [JavaScript is available to automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/).

The equivalent of your code would be:

```
var finder = Application('Finder');

finder.activate();
finder.windows[0].position = {x: 607, y: 276};
finder.windows[0].close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can use node js  module: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-applescript